# How to save data in a *table view* on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to swift and iOS development, so I'm still learning how everything works in Xcode. I'm currently building a list application which uses a table view, but the list becomes empty every time I reopen the app. I've looked at tutorials on youtube and few other places but all I could find was saving data on a label, which didn't work for me on my table view. I would be really grateful if someone could guide me as to how to save data in a tableview on swift. Thank you very much!

Comment: use core data or any other database/server.

Comment: Like I said, I've just started learning, so I don't understand how to do either, sorry :(. edit: I just looked core data up, and I didn't check that box when I began the project. Is there a way to use core data now?

Answer (score 3):

There are more than a few answers and guides related to this online, so you'll have to do your own research to see which makes the most sense. One thing to note is that the way you save your data has nothing to do with your table view, which is as the name implies, just a view.

A few options:

- `UserDefaults`: This is usually best for individual values, settings,
  and flags. Unless the list is very short I probably wouldn't use
  this.
- `CoreData`: This would be the standard option that is built
  into iOS and actually integrates pretty nicely with `UITableView`
  through the use of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.
- Manual archiving
  using `NSCoding`: creating a `Data` object and saving it to the disk
  yourself. With the amount of nice persistence options available now,
  I wouldn't recommend bothering with this.
- Another third party datastore: There are a few of these, Realm.io comes to mind
  as an extremely popular and flexible option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do that